# Simplifying a complex expression for graphing on the complex plane

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So I started off with this and am asked to graph it on the complex plane.

$$
\left \{ z \in  \mathbb{C}, \left | \frac{z - 1}{z - 2} \right | \leq  3 \right \}
$$

I'm trying to simplify the expression. Letting $z = a + ib$ I got to:

$$
\frac{\sqrt{\left ( a-1 \right )^{2} + b^{2}}}{\sqrt{\left ( a-2 \right )^{2} + b^{2}}}   \leq  3
$$

which led me finally to:

$$
8a^{2} + 8b^{2} - 34a \geq  -35
$$

And I am now lost. I don't think this is what I was supposed to come up with. Am I over complicating matters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a really nice way of doing it geometrically.  You need to know the following result of classical Euclidean geometry.

**Theorem**.  Let $A,B$ be points in a plane and let $c$ be a positive number, $c\ne1$.  The locus of points $Z$ such that $(ZA)=c(ZB)$ is a circle with diameter lying on the line through $A$ and $B$.

For your question we first solve the equality $|z-1|=3|z-2|$.  This is a circle with diameter going through the complex points $1$ and $2$.  That is, the diameter lies along the real axis.  By trial and error you can see that $z=\frac{7}{4}$ and $z=\frac{5}{2}$ satisfy the equation.  Therefore these are opposite ends of the diameter, the centre is $z=\frac{17}{8}$ and the radius is $\frac{3}{8}$.

Since you have an inequality rather than an equality, your answer will be either the inside or the outside of this circle, and by trial and error it's not hard to determine which.

Answer (score 0):

$$\implies \left(a-\frac{17}8\right)^2+b^2\ge\left(\frac38\right)^2$$

So, $(a,b)$ lies on or outside the circle whose center is $\displaystyle\left(\frac{17}8,0\right)$ with radius $\frac38$ unit